# PL/SQL with Oracle Apex - Delete Validation

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

Let's say I have two oracle tables:
TEST_ENTRIES:

| ID | NAME | CAT_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Desk | 1 |
| 2 | Arm chair | 1 |
| 3 | Other business stuff | 2 |

and TEST_CATEGORIES:

| ID | NAME | VISIBLE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Furniture | 1 |
| 2 | Consumables | 1 |

I now want to write an Validation in Oracle Apex in PL/SQL, which checks the table TEST_CATEGORIES if a certain id is used in TEST_ENTRIES and if it is not used it should get deleted. Therefore I wrote something like this:

```
Declare
  id number;
Begin
  Select count(1) into id 
   from TEST_CATEGORIES
   Where name = :NAME;

  if id > 0 then
        raise_application_error(-20001,'Could not delete from sepecified tables');
  else
    DELETE FROM TEST_CATEGORIES
    WHERE ID = TEST_ENTRIES.CAT_ID
        RETURN;
  end if;
End;
```

but it does not work this way. Could anybody helps me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you, I'd create a foreign key constraint and let the database handle it. Something like this:

Sample data:

```
SQL> select * from test_categories;

        ID NAME           VISIBLE
---------- ----------- ----------
         1 furniture            1
         2 consumables          1
         3 delete me            1    --> not referenced from TEST_ENTRIES table

SQL> select * from test_entries;

        ID NAME         CAT_ID
---------- -------- ----------
         1 desk              1
         2 armchair          1
         3 other             2
```

Add a primary key to TEST_CATEGORIES (otherwise, foreign key can't reference it):

```
SQL> alter table test_categories add constraint pk_cat
  2    primary key (id);

Table altered.
```

Add a foreign key to TEST_ENTRIES:

```
SQL> alter table test_entries add constraint fk_ent_cat
  2    foreign key (cat_id)
  3    references test_categories (id);

Table altered.
```

Testing: `ID = 1` is referenced from `TEST_ENTRIES` so Oracle won't let you delete it:

```
SQL> delete from test_categories where id = 1;
delete from test_categories where id = 1
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02292: integrity constraint (SCOTT.FK_ENT_CAT) violated - child record
found
```

But, `ID = 3` isn't referenced and will successfully be deleted:

```
SQL> delete from test_categories where id = 3;

1 row deleted.

SQL>
```

---

If you want to create your own code, here's how; I'm running it in in SQL*Plus so I'm using substitution variable `&&P1_CAT_ID`. Instead of it, you'd use `:P1_CAT_ID` (i.e. a page item) and omit line #14 as it is useless in Apex.

```
SQL> rollback;

Rollback complete.

SQL> declare
  2    l_cnt number;
  3  begin
  4    select count(*)
  5      into l_cnt
  6      from test_entries e
  7      where e.cat_id = &&P1_CAT_ID;         --> you'd use :P1_CAT_ID
  8
  9    if l_cnt > 0 then
 10       raise_application_error(-20000, 'Not allowed, child records exist');
 11    else
 12       delete from test_categories
 13         where id = &&P1_CAT_ID;            --> you'd use :P1_CAT_ID
 14       dbms_output.put_line(sql%rowcount ||' row(s) deleted');
 15    end if;
 16  end;
 17  /
Enter value for p1_cat_id: 1
declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20000: Not allowed, child records exist
ORA-06512: at line 10


SQL> undefine p1_cat_id
SQL> /
Enter value for p1_cat_id: 3
1 row(s) deleted

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You *could* do this, but that is not what a validation if for. A validation is meant to *validate* the user input. For example if a user can't choose a start date that is after an end date - that is something that could fail a validation. If a validation fails, the page processes are not executed.

a *page process* is for performing a dml operation (update/insert/delete) with a legacy process or custom pl/sql

You mention in your question *a certain id is used* - what does that mean ? Is it a value the user has selected in a form ? I'm assuming it's a page item in my code below

In your case, the code would be split up in 2 parts

###### validation

```
SELECT 1 
   FROM test_categories
   WHERE name = :P1_NAME;
```

###### page process

```
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM test_categories WHERE name = :P1_NAME;
END;
```

Note that I didn't focus on the code, but more on *where* logic should go in APEX in this example. As @Littlefoot pointed out, you're better off using a foreign key constraint to prevent an accidental delete.